# Typing one character at a time in Processing

Tags: string, text, character, processing

I'm trying to display one character at a time in processing. If I type the letter "Q" for example, how can I make it so that when I type another character, it displays in the same place as the previous one but deleting the previous one in the process?

ultimately I'm trying to make a program that would show any pressed key on different fonts; but when I attempted this, the characters just keep adding in succession.

As of now, this gives me characters in succession:

```java
String letters = "";

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
  stroke(255);
  fill(0);
  textSize(16);
}

void draw() {
  background(204);
  text(letters, 0, 50);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == BACKSPACE) {
    if (letters.length() > 0) {
      letters = letters.substring(0, letters.length()-1);
    }
  } else if (textWidth(letters+key) < width) {
    letters = letters + key;
  }
}
```

How is it possible to have only one character showed at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```java
letters = letters + key;
```

Here you're adding `key` to the `letters` variable. So if `letters` is `"ABC"` and `key` is `'X'`, then `letters` will be `"ABCX"` after this line runs.

If all you want to do is display the most recent key pressed, why don't you just use the `key` value directly? That's exactly what it holds:

```java
void draw() {
  background(0);
  text(key, 25, 25);
}
```